# Utilizing Time-Dependent Covariates in Cox Regression Analysis with R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival, survminer

I'm working with **acute myeloid leukemia (AML) data**. I want to study if there are differences in **Overall Survival** between the patients who received an **allogeneic transplant** and those who did not. I have performed the **Proportional Hazards Assumption of a Cox Regression test** and plotted the residuals, and we can observe that the assumption is not satisfied. Here is the code:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
OS_AlloHCT <- coxph(Surv(SGmesos, Estadoactual) ~ AlloTPH, data = AML)  
test.ph <- cox.zph(OS_AlloHCT)
test.ph

#                 chisq df      p
#    AlloTPH       93.3  1 <2e-16
#    GLOBAL        93.3  1 <2e-16

ggcoxzph(test.ph)
```

[image]

The plot of the residuals leads us to conclude that the Proportional Hazards Assumption is not met. For this reason, and due to clinical considerations, I have decided to treat this variable as a time-dependent covariate. To do this, I have created new variables in the database: `txtime`, `start`, and `stop`.

`FechaAloTPH` indicates the transplant date, `Fechadiagnóstico` is the diagnosis date, and `Fechaúltimavisita` is the last follow-up visit. `txtime` represents the difference, in days, between the diagnosis date (Fechadiagnóstico) and the transplant date (FechaAloTPH). It needs to be a numeric variable:

```
AML$txtime <- difftime(AML$FechaAloTPH, AML$Fechadiagnóstico,"days")
AML$txtime <- as.numeric(AML$txtime)
```

`AloTPH` is a binary variable that takes the value 1 if the patient has received a bone marrow transplant and 0 if not. If the patient has received a bone marrow transplant and the days of overall survival are greater than the days until the transplant (which is logical), the start date will be set to txtime (the number of days until the transplant date). Otherwise, the start date will be set to 0.

If the patient has received a bone marrow transplant and the days of overall survival are greater than the days until the transplant (again, which is logical), the stop date will be set to SGdies (the number of days until the last visit). Otherwise, the stop date will be set to the value of txtime.

```
AML$start <- ifelse(AML$AloTPH ==1 & (AML$SGdies > AML$txtime),AML$txtime,0)
AML$stop <- ifelse(AML$AloTPH ==1 & (AML$SGdies > AML$txtime),AML$SGdies, AML$txtime)
AML$stop <- ifelse(is.na(AML$stop),AML$SGdies, AML$stop)
```

Here, we can see the variables required for the analysis:

[image]

All the variables have been previously described, and `Estadoactual` takes the value 1 if the patient is dead and 0 if they are alive.

I have created the Simon-Makuch plot:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggplot2)
model <- survfit(Surv(start,stop,Estadoactual)~AloTPH, data=AML)
ggsurvplot(model)
```

[image]

The **Cox regression model**, with the `AloTPH` variable treated as a **time-dependent covariate**, is as follows:

```
AML$Surv <- Surv(AML$start,AML$stop,AML$Estadoactual)
AML$AloTPH<- relevel(as.factor(AML$AloTPH), ref = "1")
cox_OS_AloTPH<- coxph(Surv~AloTPH,data=AML)
summary(cox_OS_AloTPH)

#             coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)  
#  AloTPH0 -0.1831    0.8327   0.1082 -1.691   0.0908 .
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#          exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
#  AloTPH0    0.8327      1.201    0.6736     1.029

# Concordance= 0.518  (se = 0.009 )
# Likelihood ratio test= 2.82  on 1 df,   p=0.09
# Wald test            = 2.86  on 1 df,   p=0.09
# Score (logrank) test = 2.87  on 1 df,   p=0.09
```

I have discovered an alternative method for creating the **Simon-Makuch plot** and conducting the **Mantel-Byar test**:

```
#install.packages("aod")
library(aod)
#install.packages("RcmdrPlugin.EZR")
library(RcmdrPlugin.EZR)
library(Rcmdr)
TempTD <- AML
Mantel.Byar(Group = "AloTPH", Event = TempTD$Estadoactual, 
            StartTime = TempTD$start, StopTime = TempTD$stop, 
            method = c("SAS", "Tominaga"), plot=0, landmark=0)
```

What do you think of this analysis? Is it correct?

Comment: Wrong kind of question for SO. Perhaps appropriate for CrossValidated.com. That said, there are comments to be made about the code used. Should do this: ``cox_OS_AloTPH<- coxph(Surv(start, stop, Estadoactual) ~ AloTPH, data=AML)` rather than constructing a `Surv` column in object: AML.